# AudioSession maximumInputNumberOfChannels returning 0

Tags: ios, swift, microphone, avaudiosession

I made an iOS plugin that captures audio data and forwards it along to a listener in the form of a byte stream. It was working flawlessly in an emulator and on various devices, but on an iPhone 6 running iOS 11.3 it is crashing during initialization. I've tracked the problem to this code:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try session.setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels(1) // This is the line that is throwing
    try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(65)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription) // Prints: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)
    return -1
}
```

As the comment shows, the error is being caused by the call to `session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration`. Looking at the documentation, it says that the call will throw if the input number is greater than `session.maximumInputNumberOfChannels`, and judging from the error message, this seems to be the case. Checking that value on this phone, it is returning 0.

What would be causing that value to be 0? As far as I can tell, I don' think it's a permissions issue, as I request microphone permissions prior to the app reaching this point in the code. The only other thing I can think of is that the phone essentially has no microphone capabilities... but it's a *phone*, so the inclusion of a microphone seems fairly standard.

EDIT: I pulled out an iPad Air that's running iOS 12, and it's having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I needed to add `session.setActive(true)` before trying to set the number of channels. I've never had to do that before, but I guess it's something you should do anyway just in case.

Answer (score -2):

AVAudioSession.sharedInstance() 
you can change it anyway,
search it?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this is essentialy just a "Google it" answer, everything I've ever read on the subject of AVAudioSession says that each app can only ever have one session obtained from `sharedInstance()`, and that multiple sessions are not only unsupported but is actually redundant.